# Remote debugging firefox on Android

Tags: android, debugging, firefox, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug remotely from firefox 68.6, on Android 4.4.2 but i can't enable wifi debug because it says that need a QR reader app (see image below for more detail, there is a link because I can't embed a image for the low reputation). I tried different QR code app, but none of them changed the situation. How can I enable this option?

Of course if I try to connect from desktop now, it says `Connection failed`.

[I refer to this option at the bottom of the page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKT6Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox requires a specific QR code scanner app – [`com.google.zxing.client.android`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) – which is silly and not very well documented. This functionality was removed some time between Firefox 68 and 80.

- [ZXing "Barcode Scanner" App on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android)
- [Offending source code](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/MOBILE5301_2017041915_RELBRANCH/mobile/android/geckoview/src/main/java/org/mozilla/gecko/util/InputOptionsUtils.java#L37) (no longer present)
- [Sort-of related bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602818)